# Move constructor and double delete

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

Initially I thought that move constructor will not call the temporary object destructor but when I try it is calling the destructor. So when we steal the data from move constructor I am getting double delete error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    : name("default")
    {
        cout<<"i am default\n";
        data = new char[20];
    }

    A(A&& t)
    : name("move")
    {
        data = t.data;
        cout<<"i am move\n";
    }

    ~A()
    {
        delete data;
        cout<<"I am done:"<<name<<endl;
    }

    char * data;
    string name;
};

A getA()
{
    A obj;
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    A test(std::move(getA()));
}
```

Comment: Well, your move constructor is broken. But what is your question?

Comment: You *sure* you stole that data? I'm pretty sure your original object still thinks it owns it, especially since you've done nothing to tell it otherwise in your mv-ctor.

Comment: I am getting double delete error when I execute this, what will be the reason?

Comment: oh..I missed  t.data = 0;

Comment: It's hard to see code that isn't there.  Suppose you step through it in a debugger, with a breakpoint on the move constructor and a breakpoint on the destructor, what happens?

Comment: C++ doesn't actually move anything. It just provides you with rvalue refs that allow us to make distinct kinds of constructors in which _you_ can move things! Good, innit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you are not actually "stealing", you're just copying, and so you'll delete 2 times the same pointer, as you noticed.

To actually "steal" the data, set the original data to `nullptr`, as it no longer belongs to that object.

```
A(A&& t)
: name("move")
{
    data = t.data;
    t.data = nullptr; //'t' doesn't own its data anymore
    cout<<"i am move\n";
}
```

You could also use [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) (thanks @RemyLebeau):

```
A(A&& t) : name("move"), data(nullptr)
{
    std::swap(data, t.data);
    cout << "i am move\n";
}
```

Comment: Consider using `std::swap()` instead: `A(A&& t) : name("move"), data(nullptr) { std::swap(data, t.data); cout<<"i am move\n"; }`

Comment: Or slightly fancier, `A(A&& t) : name("move"), data(std::exchange(t.data, nullptr)) { /* ... */ }`